# cv::error(): OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (A.size == arrays[i0]->size) in Android

Tags: android, opencv, compare

my error is

> E/cv::error(): OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (A.size == arrays[i0]->size) in void cv::NAryMatIterator::init(const cv::Mat**, cv::Mat*, uchar**, int), file /Volumes/Linux/builds/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 4442
>   E/org.opencv.imgproc: imgproc::compareHist_10() caught cv::Exception: /Volumes/Linux/builds/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:4442: error: (-215) A.size == arrays[i0]->size in function void cv::NAryMatIterator::init(const cv::Mat**, cv::Mat*, uchar**, int)
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.example.yantingchen.testopencv4, PID: 28141
>                     CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: /Volumes/Linux/builds/master_pack-android/opencv/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:4442: error: (-215) A.size == arrays[i0]->size in function void cv::NAryMatIterator::init(const cv::Mat**, cv::Mat*, uchar**, int)
>                     ]
>                         at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.compareHist_0(Native Method)
>                         at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.compareHist(Imgproc.java:753)
>                         at com.example.yantingchen.testopencv4.MainActivity.compareHist(MainActivity.java:188)
>                         at com.example.yantingchen.testopencv4.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:131)
>                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
>                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19858)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)

and my code is

```
    onCreate(){

      Mat mat1 = new Mat();
      Mat mat2 = new Mat();
      Mat mat11 = new Mat();
      Mat mat22 = new Mat();

      bitmap1 = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView1.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
      bitmap2 = ((BitmapDrawable)imageView2.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

      Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap1 , mat1);
      Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap2 , mat2);
      Imgproc.cvtColor(mat1 , mat11 , Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
      Imgproc.cvtColor(mat2 , mat22 , Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

      compareHist(mat11 , mat22);
    }
```

and my compareHist Method

```
public void compareHist(Mat srcMat , Mat desMat)
{
    srcMat.convertTo(srcMat , CvType.CV_8U);
    desMat.convertTo(desMat , CvType.CV_8U);

    double target = Imgproc.compareHist(srcMat , desMat , Imgproc.CV_COMP_CORREL);

    Log.e(TAG , "相似度: == " + target);
    Toast.makeText(this , "相似度:==" + target , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    txt1.setText("相關性CORREL" + target);//越接近1越好

    double target1 = Imgproc.compareHist(srcMat , desMat , Imgproc.CV_COMP_CHISQR);
    double target2 = Imgproc.compareHist(srcMat , desMat , Imgproc.CV_COMP_INTERSECT);
    double target3 = Imgproc.compareHist(srcMat , desMat , Imgproc.CV_COMP_BHATTACHARYYA);

    txt2.setText("卡方CHISQR" + target1);//為0最好
    txt3.setText("交集法INTERSECT" + target2);//值越大越好
    txt4.setText("距離法BHATTACHARYYA" + target3);//為0最好
}
```

and I use two different sized photos , and I get this Error,
how can I solve this error

Thank you

Comment: `compareHist` needs both inputs to be of the same size, and yours are not. The histograms of the two images will have the same size, but you're not computing the histogram anywhere. So, **why you intend to compare the histograms, but you never compute the histograms?**

Comment: The original is the case, then I ask how to calculate and let him become the same size of the map to compare it
and Thank you for your response.